# Tomcat docker-compose running web app

Tags: tomcat, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Was wondering if any one has attempted at running tomcat using docker-compose and successfully run a web app.  I have put together the following docker-compose file.

```
tomcat:
   image: bitnami/tomcat:latest
   environment:
      - TOMCAT_USERNAME=root
      - TOMCAT_PASSWORD=password
   links:
     - db:mysql
   ports:
     - 8585:8080
   volumes:
     - ./tomcat:/bitnami/tomcat
db:
   image: mariadb
   ports:
      - 3636:3306
   environment:
   MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
phpmyadmin:
   image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
   links:
      - db:mysql
   ports:
      - 8689:80
   environment:
      MYSQL_USERNAME: root
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      PMA_HOST: mysql
```

The containers all run and I can access the apache 'web application manager' where I have deployed my .war file which shows to be running.

[image]

But when I try access it from the browser I am getting a 404

[image]

If anyone could help or point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.

Sorry should of pointed out I am using Thyme-leaf for web templating so the index.html file is in the resources/templates folder and I have my Controller mapping to it. And I also had this problem before I starting using Thyme-leaf.   Everything is working on a local environment just not in the container.

Comment: Does your `new_test` app have an `index.html` in the root folder? The Tomcat error indicates that it does not...

Comment: @nwinkler yes have the index.html in there put also get the 404 when I try to make a request for that too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK guys finally figured this out issue was to do with the tomcat dependency I had in my pom

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Even though the scope is set to provided the container does not seem to like it, I have removed the dependency and everything is working as expected.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

your `new_test.war` is missing the `index.htm`l file, if you say its in there check its in the correct location root folder. use 7zip or similar tool to open your `war/archive` to see where the file is located.

Comment: Sorry should of mentioned that I am using Thyme-leaf for web templates, so the the index.html is found in the resources/templates folder will up date question.